# I want to draw attention to a question with no answers. How much rep would you advise that I already have before I offer a bounty?

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounties

<sub>**Note:** I am explicitly asking for your opinion to help me make this decision</sub>

I have a [question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61560442/how-do-i-properly-get-a-batch-prediction-from-google-cloud-automl-using-a-chrome) with no answers. I am aware that this is a very specific issue, but I still want to draw attention to it with a bounty. However, I am a low-rep user on SO, with just 249 points.

How much rep would you advise that I already have before I offer a bounty?

I really need an answer to this question, but I'm not desperate and I'm not sure if 50-150 rep is worth it since it is a massive chunk of my ~250 rep.

Comment: No one can make that call for you.

Comment: If it was me, I would save up 300 rep before offering 50 as a bounty. You gain privileges at 200 and 250 https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges Waiting until you clear that 250 privilege by 50 would make sure you don't lose any privileges earned. I don't know how good you are are making rep back, so don't know how valuable 50 rep is on it's own to you but this is something to consider..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the privileges page of the site to see what privileges you're going to lose.

Then think what you actually use the site for.

Think for a while, and put the lost privileges against the need to get answers. Then choose the option that has more value in your mind. Keep in mind, that you won't be able to undo the bounty, so first try to make a proper edit to the question, that will also bump it.

Comment: [Sample privileges page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges?tab=all). But it is a bit too terse. Better is *[What are the reputation requirements for privileges on sites, and how do they differ per site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/what-are-the-reputation-requirements-for-privileges-on-sites-and-how-do-they-di/160292#160292)* (note that the footnotes are not unimportant).

Comment: Thanks @P.Mort and by the way... who's Clay?